# Iframe-Resizer not working on Desktop. Failed to Execute.

Tags: iframe-resizer

I have tried getting this I-Frame Resizer to work on a friends site for hours now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It works fine on my iPhone but not at all on desktops. Any browser.

URL is http://www.tomhammangphotography.com/blog.html

In the console I'm receiving the same error twice - "iframeResizer.min.js:8 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://www.tomhammangphotography.com') does not match the recipient window's origin."

I have my options set in the js file iframe.js, and have the windowResizer embedded into the blog header.

Javascript Files are calling correctly as far as I can tell.

I have the checkOrigin set to False, and the height calculator set to lowest Element.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

~Trent

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got it to work. The issue was coming from my Wordpress Blog Settings.

Once I added "www" to my wordpress blog URL, the iframe resizing worked perfectly.

I knew it was something funny like that.

Best to All.

T